Japan - Does Engineering work as a Contractor satisfy the "Engineer/Specialist in humanities/Int'l services" visa conditions?
I moved to Japan under a "Engineer/Specialist in humanities/Int'l services" visa a year ago, and have been working fulltime at an engineering company located in Japan. Unfortunately the company folded, and I'm left to find a new position to keep my visa. I found another large company in Japan who offered me a new fulltime engineering position, but for the probation period (6 months) I'll technically be employed as a full time contractor (keiyaku sha-in) and not actually a permanent employee (sei-sha-in).
Will this be valid to upkeep my Visa, or will I have to keep looking for a new job? Sorry if this isn't the right place to ask. I tried looking on my own and couldn't work it out.

Yes, that will still constitute acceptable activities under your status of residence. I moved to Japan under the "Engineer/Specialist in humanities/Int'l services" SOR and my first role (for which my visa was granted) was a contract gig, so it's fine.
Just be aware that you have to notify immigration within 2 weeks of leaving an employer and within 2 weeks of joining an employer: https://www.moj.go.jp/isa/applications/procedures/nyuukokukanri10_00015.html
